# Is Patreon a viable way to implement a subscription-based monetization strategy?

Tags: browser-based-games, monetization

I am looking for an alternative to premium currency and microtransactions as a monetization strategy for a persistent browser game. Subscriptions seem the straightforward solution, though I don't want to set up my own payment system.

**Can I use Patreon (or similar membership platforms) as a way to limit access to a premium server, or access to the game itself, for patrons only?**

I couldn't find it in their guidelines if this sort of implementation is allowed.

Comment: SteamSpy does, in effect, do this. However, there is no automation of this approach in Patreon, afaict. which means it is not a reliable, scalable approach for you to use.

Comment: If you've already checked their published terms, then the only way to get an authoritative, up to date answer is to ask the platfrom's representatives yourself. Any answer we could give you would amount to Internet hearsay or "well, that other game did it" which is probably not the stable foundation you want to build your business plan upon.

Comment: That is fair; thank you both for your comments. Should I close this thread?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After further digging into Patreon material, I found a [blog post](https://blog.patreon.com/6-membership-based-business-models-you-can-use-on-patreon-today) from them that answers my question. It puts subscription as one of the one of the business models one can use the platform for.

> ### 6. Service/Product Model
>
> Defined as: a specific service or product offered in exchange for
> monthly pledges.
>
> This category is closer to many ‘normal’ businesses: think software in
> exchange for monthly subscriptions, recurring consulting appointments,
> or commissions. It’s an exchange of time or physical goods for money.